# Pandas DataFrame using different functions as rows

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, rows

I have this

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[42.5,39.5,37.2,40,41,38,38.2,39.7],
                   'B': [13.3,12.8,12.1,12.3,13.3,12.2,12.4,12.8]})
```

and I want a DataFrame with the describe functions of columns ['A'] and ['B'] plus other columns, in this case I add columns ['T'] and ['I'].

Columns ['A'] and ['B'] below display the results of function df['A'].describe(), df['B'].describe()

Here is desired result:

```
    T   I         A      B
0   F   n       8.00    8.00
1   F   avg     39.51   12.65
2   F   std     1.72    0.47
3   F   min     37.20   12.10
4   F   25%     38.15   12.27
5   F   50%     39.60   12.60
6   F   75%     40.25   19.25
7   F   max     42.50   13.30
```

I have tried code below but it did not work:

```
df2=pd.DataFrame({
                 'T':['F','F','F','F','F','F','F','F'],
                 'I':['n','avg','std','min','25%','50%','75%','max'],
                 'A':[df['A'].describe()],
                 'B':[df['B'].describe()],
                 })
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If order of DataFrame `df2` matching with order of output functions you can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with [`DataFrame.describe`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html) for all columns:

```
df2=pd.DataFrame({
                 'T':['F','F','F','F','F','F','F','F'],
                 'I':['n','avg','std','min','25%','50%','75%','max'],
                 })


df3 = pd.concat([df2, df.describe().reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)

#if need specify some columns for describe
#df3 = pd.concat([df2, df[['A','B']].describe().reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)
print (df3)
   T    I          A          B
0  F    n   8.000000   8.000000
1  F  avg  39.512500  12.650000
2  F  std   1.722488   0.475094
3  F  min  37.200000  12.100000
4  F  25%  38.150000  12.275000
5  F  50%  39.600000  12.600000
6  F  75%  40.250000  12.925000
7  F  max  42.500000  13.300000
```

Or you can use `rename` for values of index which necessary and then add column by `T` by [`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html):

```
df3 = df.describe().rename_axis('I').rename({'count':'n','mean':'avg'}).reset_index()
df3.insert(0, 'T', 'F')
print (df3)
   T    I          A          B
0  F    n   8.000000   8.000000
1  F  avg  39.512500  12.650000
2  F  std   1.722488   0.475094
3  F  min  37.200000  12.100000
4  F  25%  38.150000  12.275000
5  F  50%  39.600000  12.600000
6  F  75%  40.250000  12.925000
7  F  max  42.500000  13.300000
```